# Query string is too long. Methods to shorten URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The user is able to filter Recipes by Tags (check box)

```
<input asp-for="AllTags[i].TagId" type="hidden"> <input asp-for="AllTags[i].Name" type="hidden">
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="AllTags[i].isChecked" class="checkbox" id="@Model.AllTags[i].TagId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.AllTags[i].Name)
```

[image: Image of selecting filters to filter recipes]

and in doing so it creates a query string like so on, form submit (GET):

```
https://localhost:89514/?AllTags%5B0%5D.TagId=19&AllTags%5B0%5D.Name=Cake&AllTags%5B0%5D.isChecked=true&AllTags%5B1%5D.TagId=28&AllTags%5B1%5D.Name=Pinapple&AllTags%5B2%5D.TagId=40&AllTags%5B2%5D.Name=Four&AllTags%5B3%5D.TagId=45&AllTags%5B3%5D.Name=AppleFour&AllTags%5B4%5D.TagId=46&AllTags%5B4%5D.Name=AppleFive&AllTags%5B5%5D.TagId=55&AllTags%5B5%5D.Name=AppleFourteen&AllTags%5B6%5D.TagId=70&AllTags%5B6%5D.Name=AppleFiveteen&AllTags%5B7%5D.TagId=72&AllTags%5B7%5D.Name=Bread&AllTags%5B8%5D.TagId=103&AllTags%5B8%5D.Name=DF&AllTags%5B9%5D.TagId=104&AllTags%5B9%5D.Name=FFCG&AllTags%5B10%5D.TagId=105&AllTags%5B10%5D.Name=FFFa&AllTags%5B11%5D.TagId=106&AllTags%5B11%5D.Name=FFFF&AllTags%5B12%5D.TagId=108&AllTags%5B12%5D.Name=Q&AllTags%5B13%5D.TagId=109&AllTags%5B13%5D.Name=QQ&AllTags%5B14%5D.TagId=110&AllTags%5B14%5D.Name=DSDDDSSDwQWQWQQQEQEEEQ&AllTags%5B15%5D.TagId=111&AllTags%5B15%5D.Name=DSDSDKJSNHDJKSBDK&AllTags%5B16%5D.TagId=112&AllTags%5B16%5D.Name=DSSD&AllTags%5B17%5D.TagId=114&AllTags%5B17%5D.Name=SDSDSDSDSDSD&AllTags%5B18%5D.TagId=117&AllTags%5B18%5D.Name=Ok&SortBy=Relevance&PageSize=2&AllTags%5B0%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B1%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B2%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B3%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B4%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B5%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B6%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B7%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B8%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B9%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B10%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B11%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B12%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B13%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B14%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B15%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B16%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B17%5D.isChecked=false&AllTags%5B18%5D.isChecked=false
```

I send back to the controller whether the tag was checked `isChecked`, the `Name`, and `TagId`

If the user checks too many Tags then I get an error:

`Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.`

Apparently, I can increase the length limit but I see the the max URL character length is 2000 characters and currently the URL is at 2100 characters.

I was wondering, what are some methods to reduce the query string? I've been looking at other sites that filter products and they seem to have some sort of encryption.

For example,
`https://www.newegg.com/p/plN=100160979%20600416629%20600416632%20600987767%204131%208000%201065728267%20601311403%20600417635%20600012200`

and

```
https://pricespy.co.nz/category.php?k=s336934912&sort=property%3A89&direction=asc&catId=393
```

Ideally, I like pricespys method where it doesn't matter how many options are filtered for, the URL says the same length (the numbers "k=s336934912" just change).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the following:

http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Query-String-Encrypt-Decrypt-in-asp-net

Basically you can just take the query string url as a basic string and encrypt it then decrypt it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass Name, TagId and whether it was checked or not!
You have tagNames in your database. You only need to pass tagId that checked. Something like this.

/Search?tags=1&tags=5&tags=6

Just change your controller and view like this

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AllTags()
{
    var AllTagsModel = ... Create your model 
    return View(AllTagsModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AllTags(IEnumerable<int> id)
{ ... }
```

view

```
<form asp-action="AllTags" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AllTags)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="item-@item.TagId" name="id" value="@item.TagId" checked="@(item.isChecked ? "Checked" : null)"/>
        <label for="item-@item.TagId"> Item @item.Name </label><br>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: input of type="checkbox", only accepts Boolean with asp-for="(e.g)AllTags[i].isChecked ". How do I pass an Id that was checked if Id is an int?

Answer (score 0):

**?filter=tag:1,tag:2,tag:3**

view

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="item-@item.TagId" name="id" value="tag:@(item.TagId)"/>
```

controlller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AllTags(string filter)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
        {
            var list = filter.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(item =>
                   {
                       var subItems = item.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                       return new SplitModel
                       {
                           TagId = Convert.ToInt64(subItems[1]),
                           Search = subItems[0],
                       };
                   })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.TagId).Select(x => new { TagId = x.Key, List = x.Select(j => j.Search) })
                   .ToList();

            if (list?.Any() == true)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    // code
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
    
    
    public class SplitModel
    {
        public long TagId { get; set; }
        public string Search { get; set; }
    }
```